# How to fit 15 minutes onto Google Calendar in single lines

Tags: google-calendar, google-calendar-reminders

I divide my time up to 15 minute intervals.
But Google Calendar seems to want to treat all of my reminders as needing 30 minutes to display, even if they are spaced 15 minutes apart, resulting in half of each reminder overlapping on the previous which cuts the horizontal space for each in half as show in the screen shot below:
[image]

As you can see, I can't even read what each reminder is for!  I have gone to `Settings` and under `Event settings` I have set the default duration to 15 minutes.  This seems to be the only relevant setting.

On Android I can zoom in and out by pinch to zoom, but this is never enough to let each task have it's own line.  In a browser, the only way I can figure to zoom in and out is to alter the browser's zoom factor, and this also does not achieve the desired effect.

If it makes any difference, the same thing happens with events, but I only use events for things that are at least half an hour in length.

Comment: Woohoo! I just noticed today that Google Calendar now has the native functionality to display a 15-minute appointment at the proportional height you want it, that is, only taking up one-quarter of the hour-long slot. Finally! At least Google got there in the end, after years of feature requests. :)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question Google Calendar switched Reminders To Tasks. Tasks has a date and time, not a duration. Ref. https://blog.google/products/workspace/tasks-reminders/, https://support.google.com/calendar/thread/205408965?hl=en

Comment: @Rubén Don't even get me started on that... Reminders work for me.  Tasks... not so much.

Answer (score -1):

Google Calendar does NOT allow 4 `VIEW` entries per hour.
You would have to change to OUTLOOK which does allow this.

Comment: Is there any alternative app with that feature though? Maybe a desktop app?